# chef-client showing error message

Tags: chef-infra, chefdk

I've an environment where the chef version is:

```
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.18.30
```

When I run the chef-client command, I get the following error:

```
root@localhost product]# chef-client
[2017-11-06T15:38:25-05:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2017-11-06T15:38:25-05:00] WARN: Did not find config file: /etc/chef/client.rb, using command line options.
[2017-11-06T15:38:25-05:00] WARN: *****************************************
Starting Chef Client, version 12.14.89
Creating a new client identity for localhost using the validator key.

================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "localhost"
================================================================================

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
[2017-11-06T15:38:32-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2017-11-06T15:38:32-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 07 seconds
[2017-11-06T15:38:32-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-11-06T15:38:32-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-11-06T15:38:32-05:00] ERROR: I can't write your private key to /etc/chef/client.pem - check permissions?
[2017-11-06T15:38:32-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I'm new to chef. I cannot upgrade or change versions in this environment but a build is failing because of this issue. Any insights on why this is happening?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run `chef-client` on a machine that has not been boostrapped, meaning it doesn't have the authentication keys to access the Chef server or a config file with the info on where that Chef Server is. You can use `knife bootstrap` normally, but check with others at your company (or whatever) as to what you usually use, might be something else.